# How to remove combinations in one list that are present in another list?

Tags: python, tuples, combinations

I have two lists that contain tuples.

I want to remove all the combinations in list `seq2` that are elements of list `k1`. How can I do this?

```
from itertools import permutations

seq2 = permutations(['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n'], 5)

k2 = []
k1 = [('y','h'),('p','o'),('h','n'),('t','p'),('n','o')]

for j in list(seq2):
   k2.append(j)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from itertools import permutations

# parameter r-length needs to be 2 rather than 5 as in previous code
seq2 = permutations(['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n'], 2)

k2 = []
k1 = [('y','h'),('p','o'),('h','n'),('t','p'),('n','o')]

for j in list(seq2):
    # check if element j is not in k1
    if j not in k1:
        k2.append(j)

print(k2)
```

[OUT]

```
[('p', 'y'),
 ('p', 't'),
 ('p', 'h'),
 ('p', 'n'),
 ('y', 'p'),
 ('y', 't'),
 ('y', 'o'),
 ('y', 'n'),
 ('t', 'y'),
 ('t', 'h'),
 ('t', 'o'),
 ('t', 'n'),
 ('h', 'p'),
 ('h', 'y'),
 ('h', 't'),
 ('h', 'o'),
 ('o', 'p'),
 ('o', 'y'),
 ('o', 't'),
 ('o', 'h'),
 ('o', 'n'),
 ('n', 'p'),
 ('n', 'y'),
 ('n', 't'),
 ('n', 'h')]
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the permutations will have elements that are present in your `k1` list. So in that sense you would have an empty list. But I assumed that is not what you'd want, so my interpretation:

Maybe you would like to filter out those permutations which have two consequent elements present in `k1` (`disallowed_pairs`) list.

In that case, there is a very handy library: `more_itertools` which you can use to create a window view of your permutation elements. This way you can check if any of those elements are present in your *disallowed set* and leave them out of your result list.

```py
from itertools import permutations
from more_itertools import windowed


perms = permutations(['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n'], 5)
disallowed_pairs = {('y', 'h'), ('p', 'o'), ('h', 'n'), ('t', 'p'), ('n', 'o')}
result = [
    perm
    for perm in perms
    if not any(
        window_view in disallowed_pairs
        for window_view in windowed(perm, 2)
    )
]
```

If this is not what you imagined, feel free to clarify.